# angular binding not working when change property on here setter

Tags: angular

I try to implement autocomplete with free text adding.

In the example, i try to remove the '(new)' text from selected name, but without success .

```
  get selected(){return this._selected}
  set selected(value){
    if(!value.id){
      value.id = 3
      value.name = value.name.replace(NEW,'')
      this.options.push(value)
      this.selected = value
      return;
    }
    this._selected = value;
  }
```

[stackbliz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vc2unk?file=app%2Fapp.ts)

Comment: You should include what it is you are trying to do, it is not clear in your question and not clear in the code. What happens that should not be happening or what is not happening that should?

Comment: The text box should be empty after blur when text is "1"

Comment: post a SSCCE for better help

Answer (score 0):

To make it work, simply put `return` at the end of if statement - if you don't, the setter continues to execute and resets the value to `{ text: "1" }`, which was the setter argument:

```
set item(value) {
    if (value.text === "1") { 
        this._item = { text: '' };
        return;
    }
    this._item = value;
}
```

---

`setTimeout(() => this.item = { text: '' }, 0)` is working, because you are using setTimeout function, which puts it's callback function at the end of JS thread's execution stack, even if time is set to 0.

Comment: Hi, i changed my question for what i really try to do